# Mac Pro (2013- black can) and non mac monitor?

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport

I am looking to buy a Mac Pro here in the next month but I'd like to use a Samsung 4k monitor. It has 2, HDMI ports and 1 Displayport. I understand the Mac Pro has thunderbolt2 ports, which, correct me if I'm wrong are the same type of port. Can I take advantage of the 4k capabilities of the samsung using a display port to thundebolt2 connection? thx

Answer (score 1):

Given no detail on the Samsung display, it seems like you should be able to. Thunderbolt ports can handle Displayport connections. The [tech specs](https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/specs/) for the machine claim 3x5k, so a single 4k should be fine. You'll need a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.

Read about Single Stream (SST) and Multi Stream (MST) displays here: [Using 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT202856)